# How to connect to Etherscan Ropsten API using python

Tags: etherscan, ropsten, explorer-api

I want to connect to the etherscan Ropsten test-net with python:

```
URL = 'https://api-ropsten.etherscan.io/api?module=contract&action=getsourcecode&address=0x1c7f98370206b4d44bfbb011c65bc582fcdae4fe&apikey='+ API_key
s = requests.Session()
response = s.get(URL)
```

The response code is always Forbidden 403. 
I tested with curl the same url and it works.
I tried to use py-etherscan-api, but there are no examples how to connect to Ropsten.

Comment: Hi there. Here's the Ropsten connection code from `py-etherscan-api`, which definitely worked last time I ran the associated test code -> https://github.com/corpetty/py-etherscan-api/blob/1165709a41b61c724761144b6c070dd82581e153/etherscan/client.ropsten.py#L107

Comment: @RichardHorrocks Same problem connecting to Ropsten
Testing with:
from etherscan.client import Client


c = Client( address = "0x40ee8545373109ebf5d6dfac420ebbf96d09bf76", api_key="3EUHGMN7XGMM5YKJ6T98SV7H652CFD1PDB")
c.PREFIX = "https://api-ropsten.etherscan.io/api?"
c.build_url()

c.connect()

Comment: How did you pass this problem?

Comment: Using a request header from another source 

REQUESTS_HEADERS = {
    "User-Agent": "https://github.com/AndreMiras/pyetheroll",
}
response = requests.get(URL, headers=REQUESTS_HEADERS)